# SQL Server stored procedure running very slow

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, optimization

**My scenario**: I have a table with 10M+ rows & 10 columns (Table name: `Giggerdata`). I have my stored procedure designed such that when I pass two parameters (`pageNumber, pageSize`), it divides the `Giggerdata` table records up into pages (each page having 10M/`pageSize` records). It will only return those records on the `pageNumber` passed in.

I call the stored procedure from an external service which iterates through my table in batches of 30 MB (that's the limit for the API I'm using). I would effectively iterate through this table page by page (each page having 30MB worth of records) and push that data through another API.

I need to speed this stored procedure up as it takes >3 minutes get results with `pageNumber = 1` and `pageSize = 400,000`, which is > 1 hour to get my entire table exported through this iterative fashion (unacceptable for my application).

I've read up on stored procedure issues, and have tried altering my stored procedure to take into account the parameter sniffing; would someone be able to look at my stored procedure and determine whether I've properly implemented the local parameter solution?

Are there other measures I can take to speed things up?

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mySP]
    @pageNumber INT, 
    @pageSize INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @locpageNumber INT, @locpageSize INT

    SELECT @locpageNumber = @pageNumber, @locpageSize = @pageSize 

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.GiggerData
    ORDER BY Col1
        OFFSET @locpageSize * (@locpageNumber - 1) ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @locpageSize ROWS ONLY
    OPTION (RECOMPILE)
END
```

Test code:

```
DECLARE @return_value INT
EXEC    @return_value = dbo.[mySP]
            @pageNumber = 41,
            @pageSize = 500000

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Comment: What's the query plan look like? Is the clustered index on Col1?

Comment: Query it all at once from the database (as though you were unioning all the sets together). Then stream it out of memory to your api.

Comment: If you have to do it iteratively, if most of your calls are going to be the same, you might not want to recompile that statement every time. M aybe only if you pass it a certain parameter or something. Probably wouldn't make the difference between 3 minutes and 60, but it might help

Comment: There is no index (Col1 has duplicates and blanks). The solution will work for different applications (not sure how it will be queried once exported).

Comment: Also: have you tried tweaking the page size to see if you can get any optimisations there? This might actually be a case where it's faster to use the client side library rather than an SP, i.e.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/paging-through-a-query-result

Comment: You can create an index on duplicates and blanks. I suggest you start with that

Answer (score 0):

Pagination using `OFFSET` and `FETCH` will become progressively slower with each page since SQL Server still needs to start for the beginning of the ordered row set. If `GiggerData_Key` is a unique clustered index, you can use a more efficient key based pagination method:

```
SELECT TOP (500000) *
FROM dbo.GiggerData
WHERE GiggerData_Key > @Last_GiggerData_Key_Returned
    OR @Last_GiggerData_Key_Returned IS NULL --first page
ORDER BY GiggerData_Key`;
```